# Result of awk as search pattern for grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

here is a piece of log

```
21:36 b05808aa-c6ad-4d30-a334-198ff5726f7c new
22:21 59996d37-9008-4b3b-ab22-340955cb6019 new
21:12 2b41f358-ff6d-418c-a0d3-ac7151c03b78 new
12:36 7ac4995c-ff2c-4717-a2ac-e6870a5670f0 new
```

i print it by awk '{print $2}' st.log
so i got

```
b05808aa-c6ad-4d30-a334-198ff5726f7c
59996d37-9008-4b3b-ab22-340955cb6019
2b41f358-ff6d-418c-a0d3-ac7151c03b78
7ac4995c-ff2c-4717-a2ac-e6870a5670f0
```

now i need to pass it to grep, in this manner

```
awk '{print $2}' |xargs -i grep -w "pattern from awk" st.log
```

I need exactly how to pass each founded record from awk to grep. I do not need other solutions, because my task is more complicated, than this piece. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  You're pulling one column out of the file, then grepping for that line in the file again?  What's the ultimate goal of doing this?

Comment: @EricRenouf because there are several step by step operations hich are connected with each other. So i need exactly that i asked. i need to find list of keywords and after that for each keyword from list grep file to find records.

Comment: But if you're getting `$2` from every line, then finding the lines that have at least one `$2` in them from the same file, it's always going to be the same file over again, right?  Unless the `awk` and `grep` are actually working on different files and not `st.log` like you say in the question

Comment: @EricRenouf you are correct, i want to do it over the same file. i can't search everything by one search, because lines are interconnected.Example:  So i need to filter out for  field#5, from this output i have to take another fields#2, after that i have to go trough the input file again to search all records which are cnnected with #2 and to check for this fields field #3, if check is good i will print all records with this field.

Comment: Then I suspect a shorter path to the same output would be `cat st.log`, but if you have to use `awk` and `grep` both I'd go with @cyrus answer

Comment: @EricRenouf in Cyrus answer there are also two files :( because piece of log and st.log is the same

Comment: Just replace `piece_of_log` with `st.log` and it'll be just fine

Comment: So you want to use awk to print every $2 from st.log and then grep the result of that in st.log, right? Just do `cat st.log`, it'll be faster. If you need anything else then [edit] your question to provide something that actually demonstrates what it is you're trying to do so we can stop trying to solve the problem you've described so far and try to help you with your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

With bash and grep:

```
grep -f <(awk '{print $2}' piece_of_log) st.log
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for awk:

```
grep -Ff <(cut -d' ' -f2 log)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for the replace string option:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
          names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted  blanks  do  not
          terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline
          character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

Like this:

```
awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} grep -w {} st.log
```